# Getting invalid column error when trying to query table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table `Employee` in my database - these are the columns:

```
EmployeeId   Name  CreatedDate   UpdatedDate
```

This is my base class for domain entities:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     
     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     
     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Domain entities:

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Employee");
        builder.HasKey(e=>e.Id);
        //other configurations
    }
}

public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

   public MyDatabaseContext(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
        _configuration = configuration;
         Database.EnsureCreated(); 
   }

   public DbSet<Employee> Employee {get; set; }

   public void Save()
   {
        this.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

I already had existing database created so I created all this domain models and configuration based on existing database tables and relationships (`No migrations`).

Now when I am trying to get list of employees like this:

```
var myDatabaseContext = new MyDatabaseContext();
var emp = myDatabaseContext.Employee.ToList();
```

I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'Id'

How do I make my base class property `Id` work with my individual tables as primary key with different names?

I'm using Entity Framework Core v6.0.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the definition for the column name. Right now EF Core is looking for a column called `Id`:

```
builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("EmployeeId");
```

The docs for this are located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#column-names

Comment: Can you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74008866/navigation-property-are-null-when-querying-parent-entity